# Real Analysis, Folland problem 5.5.56

Tags: functional-analysis

5.21 Proposition - If $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$ then $<x_n,y_n>\rightarrow <x,y>$.

> problem 5.5.56 - If $E$ is a subset of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, $(E^{\perp})^{\perp}$ is the smallest closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ containing $E$.

Attempted proof - Let $E\subset \mathcal{H}$, we define $$E^{\perp} = \{x\in \mathcal{H}:<x,y> = 0 \ \forall \ y\in E\}$$
by what Folland says, from proposition 5.21 and the linearity of the inner product in its first argument that $E^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. Now we need to show that $(E^{\perp})^{\perp}$ is the smallest closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ containing $E$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Any suggestions to the latter above is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that : $(E^{\perp})^{\perp}=\overline{E}$

So you know that $E^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. So you have $\mathcal{H}=E^{\perp}\oplus (E^{\perp})^{\perp}=(E^{\perp})^{\perp}\oplus E^{\perp}$. Also $\overline{E}$ is a closed subspace so $\mathcal{H}=\overline{E} \oplus (\overline{E})^{\perp} = \overline{E} \oplus E^{\perp}$

Since $\overline{E} \subseteq (E^{\perp})^{\perp}$, you have $\overline{E} = (E^{\perp})^{\perp}$